# Handling multiple php version with Nginx in Mamp 4.x

Tags: php, nginx, config, mamp

I know we can handle different request using nginx by routing them to the wanted php version (see eg. [here](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/)).

The status :

- I changed my web server to Nginx in MAMP settings
- I'm currently served at `http://localhost:7888/`, successfully

What I need to configure is :

- serve the app1 using php5.30
- serve another app2 using php7.1

What I did :

- I added `/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/sites-available/app1` and `/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/sites-available/app2` according to [the eg. setup](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/#example-setup)
- I restarted MAMP (so nginx)

I desperately googled solutions but didn't found working solution, does anyone here can help to have such config? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add in more details. Where are you stuck at. Do you get some errors. Its very difficult to deduce some data from *didn't found working solution*

Comment: Did you tried the config examples from the article you've provided ?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: updated my question.

Comment: @Tony: yes, I just tried to mimic the setup from this config

Comment: Do you have symlinks to this configs in _/Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx/sites-enabled_ directory ?

Comment: @Tony: No, i didn't add that. Links is needed if we use standalone Nginx (config should be in /etc/nginx). However MAMP already provides nginx and puts config in `Applications/MAMP/conf/nginx`. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Try to add them. I think nginx is still looking for configs in _sites-enabled_ directory

Comment: yes but, nothing happened :(